# Как найти координаты места с большим количеством белого?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Картинка]

Подскажите пожалуйста как найти координаты с большим количеством белого?Заранее благодарен

```
img = cv2.imread("image.png")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_range = np.array([106, 69, 52])

upper_range = np.array([255, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
cv2.imshow("original", img)
cv2.imshow("blue_signs", mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Попробуйте выделить контуры и найти максимальную площадь контура.

Comment: Контуры тут совсем не нужны. Нужно для начала правильно подобрать диапазоны в inRange (сейчас они неправильные). Затем  connectedComponentsWhitStats выдаст и центроиды и bbox'ы. Компоненты можно отфильтровать по площади.

Comment: Выложите исходную  цветную картинку.

Comment: Добавил исходную картинку

Comment: Я нашёл rgb середины мозайки(106, 69, 52),пытаюсь найти координаты этого скопления цвета

Comment: Замечательно, а вы в курсе, что вы ищите не в RGB, а в HSV и там числа будут немного другие?

Comment: Понял,значит нужно перекодировать